# Why awk script is shuffling the last two fields?

Tags: text-processing, awk

My working file looks like this

```
Time[s]       A_in          B_in          C_in          D_in          E_in
0.000000E+00  1.120200E-02  1.432000E-01  2.331500E-04  2.349800E-03  2.800000E-03
2.500000E-01  1.751279E-04  1.553696E-01  3.172887E-09  7.512772E-09  5.009619E-09
5.000000E-01  1.741500E-04  1.553710E-01  3.102978E-09  7.609057E-09  4.952014E-09
7.500000E-01  1.733357E-04  1.553721E-01  3.037365E-09  7.730931E-09  4.893341E-09
```

My desired output is

```
Column_header = ID  Time[s]   A_in    Time[s]   B_in    Time[s]  C_in    Time[s]    D_in   Time[s]   E_in
```

My present code output is

```
Column_header = ID  Time[s]   A_in    Time[s]   B_in    Time[s]  C_in    Time[s]    E_in   Time[s]   D_in
```

Here is my snippet

```
Column_headers=$(awk ' BEGIN{OFS="  ";}
FNR==1 { for (n=1;n<=NF;n++) { if ($n ~ /_in$/) cols[$n]=n; }}

   NR==1 { 
        # print header
        printf "ID" " "
    }
END {
             for (c in cols) {printf " " "Time[s]" "    " c} 

    }

' file.txt
```

As you can see the problem is my code is shuffling the last two columns, which I have no clue at all.

Comment: Looping over awk arrays is not done in any order.

Comment: How to solve this "order" issue?

Comment: Loop from 1 to n like you did before.

Comment: Isn't there a way to sort it?

Comment: With GNU awk: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning

Comment: Thanks. 
For further reference, I solved the issue by simply adding 
`PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"`

Answer (score 0):

Just simply do as following, no need array or complicated code:

```
$ awk '{ OFS=" Time[s] "; $1="ID"; print; exit }' infile
```

to assign the result to a shell variable:

```
$ column_headers=$(awk '{ OFS=" Time[s] "; $1="ID"; print; exit }' infile)
$ echo "$column_headers"
ID Time[s] A_in Time[s] B_in Time[s] C_in Time[s] D_in Time[s] E_in
```

or if you don't know your first field header name, do as follwing:

```
$ awk '{ OFS=" "$1" "; $1="ID"; print; exit }' infile
ID Time[s] A_in Time[s] B_in Time[s] C_in Time[s] D_in Time[s] E_in
```